# Android Studio 2.3 update error in MAC OS

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

Facing issue when trying to update Android Studio 2.3 to newer version.

```
> Android Studio does not have write access to /Applications/Android
> Studio2.3.app/Contents. Please run it by a privileged user to update.
```

Answer (score 1):

Open `Terminal` and try to run this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /Applications/Android Studio2.3.app/Contents
```

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

OPEN terminal and run following commands -

Step 1 -  Open `Terminal`

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /Applications/Android\ Studio2.3.app/Contents
```

Step 2 - run below command

```
sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio2.3.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```

Step 3 - Go to Preference(Topleft) -> click `Check for updates` and update the `studio`.

Step 4 -  Close `android studio` and rerun command -

```
sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio2.3.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
```

Comment: Did this work for you? I tried this an nothing updated.